# Applying a $3$-vector to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $v,w\in V$ two vectors. Let $M$ be an endomorphism of $V$. Then $M(v)\in V$ and $M(v)\wedge v\wedge w\in\bigwedge^3 V$. What does the expression
$$(M(v)\wedge v\wedge w)v$$
mean?

Comment: Where are you seeing the notation? It would be helpful to post it in context.

Comment: Here (page 9 of the pdf) http://web.math.unifi.it/users/ottaviani/effective_quartic2.pdf

Comment: From the context you know the right-hand side of the equation just before Theorem 3.2 should be a vector in $\mathbb{C}^3$. So I think the author means $M(v)\wedge v\wedge w$ to be a scalar (e.g. maybe it's supposed to denote the *magnitude* of that wedge product). I'm not sure, though.